# Proper way to declare an enum in Managed C++ 2005?

Tags: enums, managed-c++

If I use /clr:oldSyntax the following should work:

```
public __value enum IceCreamFlavors
{
   Vanilla,
   Chocolate,
   Sardine,
};
```

what is the equivalent in non-oldSyntax? How do I declare a "managed" enum in Managed C++ for .NET 2.0?

**Edit:**
when I follow JaredPar's [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426353/proper-way-to-declare-an-enum-in-managed-c-2005#426362), then if I try to pass an IceCreamFlavor to a function with the signature:

```
OrderFlavor(IceCreamFlavors flav)
```

by running

```
OrderFlavor(IceCreamFlavors::Sardine)
```

I get the error:

```
'IceCreamFlavors Sardine' : member function redeclaration not allowed
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete sample of OrderFlavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
enum class IceCreamFlavors {
  Vanilla,
  Chocolate,
  Sardine,
};
```

Comment: When I do that, if I try to pass an IceCreamFlavor to a function with the signature: "OrderFlavor(IceCreamFlavors flav)" by running "OrderFlavor(IceCreamFlavors::Sardine)" I get "'IceCreamFlavors Sardine' : member function redeclaration not allowed"

Answer (score 0):

Are you, by any chance, trying to declare your enum inside another class?
ie:

```
public ref class Icecream
{
     public enum class flavours
     {
          Mint,
          Vanilla,
          Guac
     };
};
```

If you are, I would guess that you need to move it out so that it is its own class instead of a nested one. (Does managed c++ allow nested classes?)  My impression is that you used to be able to do it unmanaged style inside another class, but since its its own class now, you probably shouldn't be nesting them. I might be wrong. My knowledge of managed c++ and c# is kind of weak.